# Getting a sum of added cells in an ultragridview

Tags: c#, performance

> The objective of this code is to add the first 3 cells of a column
>   with the next 9 in another column and then to total out in 2
>   currencyeditor control (which is like a textbox).

Here is a demonstration of what I am adding.

- For the 1st control it's going to be the actual + adjusted (left square).
- For the 2nd control value will be the actual + original (right square).

[image: ultragridview]

I've never added different rows of an ultragridrow before this.  It works right now but doesn't look neat or professional, and I really hate the saying "at least it works" .  I was just wondering if you could help me write this code neater or more efficiently?

```cs
private void doMath()
{
    decimal actualsum = 0m;
    decimal adjustedsum = 0m;
    decimal totalsum = 0m;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        var row = dgvBudget.Rows[i];
        actualsum += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Actual_c"].Value);
    }
    for (int i = 3; i < 12; i++)
    {
        var row = dgvBudget.Rows[i];
        adjustedsum += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["PrevFY"].Value);
    }
    totalsum = (adjustedsum + actualsum);
    nbrAdjustedTotal.Value = totalsum;
    adjustedsum = 0;
    actualsum = 0;
    totalsum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        var row = dgvBudget.Rows[i];
        actualsum += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Actual_c"].Value);
    }
    for (int i = 3; i < 12; i++)
    {
        var row = dgvBudget.Rows[i];
        adjustedsum += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["BudgetAmt"].Value);
    }
    totalsum = (adjustedsum + actualsum);
    nbrOriginalTotal.Value = totalsum;
}
```

Comment: Is this a Winforms or WebForms app?  If you have access to the data that's used to populate the gridview (CodeBehind class?), I would greatly prefer to do the sum calculations directly against that data (using LINQ, perhaps), rather than navigating through UI datagrid cells to do it.  What if the order of the columns or rows changes, or the grid is tweaked to present data in a slightly different format?  This could cause your logic to break or spit out incorrect results.

Comment: @DBro it's infragistics, with Epicor which is a ERP. The format remains the same as it is set on the controls. the order or columns cannot change as there is only 12 months. I suppose I could just run it against the data but it would still be iterating through a datarows.

Comment: With LINQ, you could easily and succinctly query from the data set, without having to manually loop through rows and cells.

Comment: Not the most descriptive, but the function name made me laugh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your Concerns

> *I was just wondering if you could help me write this code neater or more efficiently?*

### Efficiency

You are looping through the data twice. Once to calculate `adjustedsum` from `column["PrevFY"]` and once for `column["BudgetAmt"]`. In both cases, `actualsum` gets calculated exactly the same way. It seems you so badly wanted to reuse variables that you forgot you could have just looped through the rows and store data in multiple variables.

```
decimal actualsum = 0m;
decimal adjustedTotal = 0m;
decimal originalTotal = 0m;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    var row = dgvBudget.Rows[i];
    actualsum += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Actual_c"].Value);
}

for (int i = 3; i < 12; i++)
{
    var row = dgvBudget.Rows[i];
    adjustedTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["PrevFY"].Value);
    originalTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["BudgetAmt"].Value);
}

nbrAdjustedTotal.Value = adjustedTotal + actualsum;
nbrOriginalTotal.Value = originalTotal + actualsum;
```

---

### Compactness (neatness)

You have recurring decimal parsing from data cells:

> ```
> Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Actual_c"].Value)
> ```

You could make a utility method for this. I'm assuming the class for the data row is called `Row`.

```
private static decimal ParseDecimal(Row row, string columnName)
{
    return Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[columnName].Value);
}
```

Further refactored:

```
decimal actualsum = 0m;
decimal adjustedTotal = 0m;
decimal originalTotal = 0m;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    var row = dgvBudget.Rows[i];
    actualsum += ParseDecimal(row, "Actual_c");
}

for (int i = 3; i < 12; i++)
{
    var row = dgvBudget.Rows[i];
    adjustedTotal += ParseDecimal(row, "PrevFY");
    originalTotal += ParseDecimal(row, "BudgetAmt");
}

nbrAdjustedTotal.Value = adjustedTotal + actualsum;
nbrOriginalTotal.Value = originalTotal + actualsum;
```

## Proposed Result

We could make the code even more compact by using LINQ's `Skip`, `Take` and `Sum` extension methods. I don't have access to the code, but I'm sure you could do something like:

```
var rows = dgvBudget.Rows.Take(3);
var actualsum = rows.Select(row => ParseDecimal(row, "Actual_c")).Sum();
var rows = dgvBudget.Rows.Skip(3).Take(9);
var adjustedTotal = rows.Select(row => ParseDecimal(row, "PrevFY")).Sum();
var originalTotal = rows.Select(row => ParseDecimal(row, "BudgetAmt")).Sum();

nbrAdjustedTotal.Value = adjustedTotal + actualsum;
nbrOriginalTotal.Value = originalTotal + actualsum;
```

This does come with a slight performance penalty, since you loop the first 3 items twice (once to skip). But it comes at a good increase in readability and compactness.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time that you used on this question. You really have taught me a few things and I appreciate it! I also love the layout you used made it really easy to read! Thanks again!